# Parse use pointer twice

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have 3 table/class such as User, Item, User_item.

In User_item, I point to Item class. To get detail of my pointer, I use this.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User_item"];
[query includeKey:@"Item"];
```

Problem is that inside my Item class, I also point back to User. May I know how to get detail from User by using query to User_item class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include key can be a key path:

```
[query includeKey:@"Item.User"];
```

and will include the detail from each level.